# Excel VBA form to select columns for another macro

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, userform

I'm trying to create a user form in excel that can be used to select columns that will be used to pass through to another macro.

Overall, I want to have a user form that can select a column/columns from a worksheet, and then this column input by the sure in the form would then be used in a macro to compare the columns. I already have a macro that compares the columns but I want it so the user can select the columns they want on a user from rather than having to go into the VBA code.

Is there anyway of doing this in a user form? If not is there any other way of doing this?

Any help would be great!! Thanks

This is the code that I am currently using to compare the columns within my spreadsheet:

```
Sub IdentifyMatches()

For X = 2 To 27
    If ((Cells((X), 2).Value <> Cells((X), 8).Value)) Then
        Cells((X), 14).Value = "ADDRESS MISMATCH"
    Else
        Cells((X), 14).Value = "Address Match"
    End If

    If ((Cells((X), 3).Value <> Cells((X), 9).Value)) Then
        Cells((X), 15).Value = "POSTCODE MISMATCH"
    Else
        Cells((X), 15).Value = "Postcode Match"
    End If

    If ((Cells((X), 4).Value <> Cells((X), 10).Value)) Then
      Cells((X), 16).Value = "COVER MISMATCH"
    Else
        Cells((X), 16).Value = "Cover Match"
    End If

    If ((Cells((X), 5).Value <> Cells((X), 11).Value)) Then
        Cells((X), 17).Value = "NAME MISMATCH"
    Else
        Cells((X), 17).Value = "Name Match"
    End If

    If ((Cells((X), 6).Value <> Cells((X), 12).Value)) Then
        Cells((X), 18).Value = "AGE MISMATCH"
    Else
        Cells((X), 18).Value = "Age Match"
    End If
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you use an input box for the user to enter the range details and use this information within the macro?

Comment: yes this is the best option, as suggested by @Gareth take column name as input  example I am suggesting take inputStr="A", this A will come by Input Box. And then you can iterate it though integer value adding it. i.e. A & i where i = integer. then it will become A1, A2 and so on. Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the following which allows the user to enter the column range (assuming that you want to set the range the entire column(s):

```
Dim strRng As String
Dim rng As Range

'Prompt the user for a column range
strRng = InputBox("Please enter the columns", , "e.g. A:B")

'Set the range to the columns entered
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(strRng)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for all your help. I don't think this is the right thing I was looking for. I have two sheets on a workbook (and want to compare certain columns on these). i already have a macro that copies to two sheets side by side but i now want to be able to select the columns that I want to compare, but I don't want the user to have to go into the VBA code to do this. I've been told it can be done, I just need a little help to try achieve this. Thanks so much for your time/effort- much appreciated

Comment: The user will not need to amend the VBA code whilst using the above as the `inputbox` handles the column letters. Are the columns being compared the same on both sheets?

Comment: Yes, the columns would be the same in both sheets it would just be the data that is different. Do I just copy the code into an inputbox? I have never heard of an input box before, sorry. Thanks again

Comment: From microsoft: `Displays a dialog box for user input. Returns the information entered in the dialog box.` Update your question with the code that you're currently using please.